# How can I resize Final Cut Pro X to fit on the screen with the dock on the left visible?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

Sometime after upgrading to MacOS 10.14 Mojave, FCPX has resized wider and seems to have a minimal width. I can't make the main window smaller than the screen width. This means it either hides behind the dock (located on the left side of the screen) or part of it disappears on the right side of the screen. I don't want to move the dock to the bottom, I don't want the autohide, and don't want the full screen option.

How can I resize FCPX to fit on the screen with the dock on the left visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try under the ”Window” menu the ”Zoom” function. That should resize the FCPX window (and any other Mac OS window) so that all is visible.

Comment: Didn't work at first, because I had hidden the dock, but this fixed the problem. Thanks.